# Bash script can't locate perl module

Tags: shell-script, perl, environment-variables

I have a shell script which isn't running [menutray](https://github.com/trizen/menutray) on `i3` startup.

Line in `.i3/config`:

```
exec ~/.i3/i3-scripts/menutray.sh
```

This is what I tried for debugging:

```
#!/bin/bash
menutray -i -u -r &>/tmp/filename
```

The contents of `filename`:

```
Can't locate Linux/DesktopFiles.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Linux::DesktopFiles module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/bin/menutray line 28.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/menutray line 28.
```

But I have `DesktopFiles.pm`:

```
$ sudo find / -name 'DesktopFiles.pm'
/home/me/.cpan/build/Linux-DesktopFiles-0.09-LZFN3P/lib/Linux/DesktopFiles.pm
/home/me/.cpan/build/Linux-DesktopFiles-0.09-LZFN3P/blib/lib/Linux/DesktopFiles.pm
/home/me/.perl5/lib/perl5/Linux/DesktopFiles.pm
```

Evidenced by:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e 'install Linux::DesktopFiles'
Reading '/home/me/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 23 Feb 2016 23:41:02 GMT
Linux::DesktopFiles is up to date (0.09).
```

`perl` variables in my `.bashrc`:

```
PATH="/home/me/.perl5/bin${PATH+:}${PATH}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/me/.perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB+:}${PERL5LIB}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/me/.perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT+:}${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/home/me/.perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/me/.perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `/home/me/.cpan/build` to your perl installation's `@INC`. As you can see in the error message, it isn't there:

```
(@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18
/usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .)
```

The simplest way to do this is to set `PERL5LIB` in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`) file:

```
export PERL5LIB="/home/me/.cpan/build:$PERL5LIB"
```

Then, either source the file (`. ~/.profile`) or log out and log back in.

That will let you run the script manually but it still won't be available when you run via `.i3/config` since that probably doesn't read `.profile`. To be sure it will work, set `PERL5LIB` explicitly in your script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
PERL5LIB="/home/max/.cpan/build:${PERL5LIB}" menutray -i -u -r &>/tmp/filename
```

Comment: I added the `perl` variables in my `.bashrc` to my question. There's already a `PERL5LIB` one, do I replace it with this or somehow add it?

Comment: Yes, you're missing the `/home/me/.cpan/build` directory as I said. Also, those would be better placed in `~/.profile`, but `~/.bashrc` will also work. The line I show in the answer will append to the current `PERL5LIB`. You can just add it.

Comment: Sorry, replace it with the `PERL5LIB` currently there? Or add it, so two will have the same name?

Comment: @Proletariat add it. The format `variable="foo:$variable"`, will simply add `foo` to the current value of `variable`. In this case, `PERL5LIB="/home/me/.cpan/build:$PERL5LIB"` will add `/home/me/.cpan/build` to the beginning of `PERL5LIB` and keep the existing values.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error in my debug file. Here's what my variables look like now in my `.bashrc`: `PATH="/home/me/.perl5/bin${PATH+:}${PATH}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/me/.perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB+:}${PERL5LIB}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL5LIB="/home/me/.cpan/build:$PERL5LIB"
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/me/.perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT+:}${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/home/me/.perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/me/.perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;`

Comment: @Proletariat why did you change all those variables? You only needed to add one line! Also, what is `${PERL5LIB+:}` supposed to mean? Try replacing all of the `PERL5LIB` lines with this one: `export PERL5LIB="/home/me/.perl5/lib/perl5:/home/me/.cpan/build:${PERL5LIB}"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36165/discussion-between-proletariat-and-terdon).

Comment: is this applicable to Cent OS 7 as well?

Comment: @krushnachChandra I don't see anything distro-specific here. Try it and see.

Comment: "Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module) (@INC contains: /home/punit/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/punit/perl5/lib/perl5 /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/punit/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
" this is what comes up every time i open a new terminal

Comment: @krushnachChandra please ask a new question. I have no idea what you are trying to do, what system you are on, what command gave you this error or anything. Please ask a new question and someone will be able to help.